# Angular 2 and SQLite connection

Tags: javascript, sqlite, angular

I have done some Angular 2 for the first time and after the html and css I now am stuck at the DB connection.
Here is what I am working with:

1. app.component.ts (Loads the templateURL)
2. overview.component.html (Is the template, 90% html 10% Modal)
3. db_basic.db (The DB File)
4. sql.js (This can get Values of the db if you do `node sql.js`)

Here the sql.js file to show how I can connect to the DB.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('../db/db_basic.db');
var check;
db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT * FROM server", function(err, row) {
        console.log(row.name);
    });
});
db.close();
```

Now, my Question would be, how do I connect to the DB and use those values in the HTML?

Extra:
[image: File structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a rest API.

The rest API seperates frontend (*angular*) from backend (database),
it serves you data and it can take care of security.

You can use a framework such as [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to make a rest API in node.

*Express.js*  can also be used to serve your static files (*angular* project)
(so you do not need appache or nginx).